# Confused about how to structure my React program with event listeners

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, event-listener, react-state

I'm building a board game in React, and I want players to be able to move pieces using arrow keys. Here's how my code is currently structured:

```
class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
  };

  move(direction) {
    ...
    this.setState({
      ...
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Board
            board={...}
          />
        </div>
        {document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
          event.preventDefault();
          if (event.code === 'ArrowUp') {
            this.move("u");
          } else if (event.code === 'ArrowRight') {
            this.move("r");
          } else if (event.code === 'ArrowDown') {
            this.move("d");
          } else if (event.code === 'ArrowLeft') {
            this.move("l");
          }
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="main">
        <Game />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here's the issue: each time move() gets called, the Game component refreshes since the state is updated (which is what I want). However, refreshing the component adds another event listener to the page. The next time I press an arrow key, move() is called twice. After that, four times (and so on).

How can I restructure my code so that the event listener only gets added once? I need move() to have access to the Game class's state. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using class components or can we refactor this to a function component?

Comment: No real reason, except that the state is reasonably complex.